# How to change bootstrap panel footer color

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, panel

I have a bootstrap panel, and I want to change the footer color like its header. I added `panel-primary` next to `panel-footer` class, but only top outline color that is changed into primary color. So, how can I change the color of panel footer ?

code :

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
     <div class="panel-heading">                  
          Panel Heading
     </div><!--.panel-heading-->

     <div class="panel-body">
           Panel Body
     </div><!--.panel-body-->

     <div class="panel-footer panel-primary">
            Panel Footer
      </div><!--.panel-footer-->
</div>
```

Comment: Note that the background colour for the heading is set on `.panel-heading` **not** `.panel-primary`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to create a custom class to apply to the panel-footer class:

> Note that panel footers **do not** inherit colors and borders when using contextual variations as they are not meant to be in the foreground. See [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#panels-footer).

```css
.panel-footer.panel-custom {
    background: red;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">Panel Heading</div>
    <!--.panel-heading-->
    <div class="panel-body">Panel Body</div>
    <!--.panel-body-->
    <div class="panel-footer panel-custom">Panel Footer</div>
    <!--.panel-footer-->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to change proper CSS to achieve that.

Defaults for Bootatrap 3 are:

```
.panel-footer {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
}
```

You can override this styles (you shouldn't add `panel-primary` class to `panel-footer`, because of the structure of Bootstrap CSS).

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:

**CSS**

```
.panel-footer{
  background-color:#337ab7;
  border-color: #337ab7;
  color: #FFFFFF;

 }
```

I override the bootstrap css, but this is not a good solution. A better way is to declare your own class and change then the colors.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mkurzweil/z7ykcco0/1/)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [Bootstrap 4.1](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/colors/#background-color) you can simply add a contextual background color class. As in Bootstrap 4.1 the Panels were replaced by Cards, a possible updated answer for your question could be:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Smlep5jCw/wG7hdkwQ/Z5nLIefveQRIY9nfy6xoR1uRYBtpZgI6339F5dgvm/e9B" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">

    <div class="card mt-4" style="width: 18rem;">
        <div class="card-header bg-success text-light">
            Card Title Here
        </div>
        <div class="card-body bg-warning">
            For example, a card with Brazilian flag colors. No explicit CSS is being used here.
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer bg-primary text-center">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-light">A White Button On Blue BG</a>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can show the CSS for these panels?

It is likely because another CSS tag has higher precedence over "panel-primary" tag.  You can try using web-developer tool in Firefox/Chrome to show what is overwriting it.